# Cant install Windows 8.1 after Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, usb-installation, usb-creator

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on my laptop. I want to go back to Windows 8.1, but it doesn't work. When I put in my install USB it doesn't work. It says "Insert proper boot device". I checked the Windows installation USB on an another PC and it worked there.

Comment: Did you format the usb before burning the iso onto it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/289559/)

Answer (score 0):

So you want to reinstall Windows.

Check your firmware (BIOS) for this:
Did you (re)enable Secure boot?
Did you (re)enable UEFI boot?
Is the installation media UEFI bootable?

Windows 8.1 requires all these things or it will not install.